# python + uwsgi: logging in mule

Tags: python, uwsgi

UWSGI starts a programmed mule with *--mule=/path/to/python/script*. Inside this script logging is configured as such:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename = '/var/log/mule.log', level = logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger('log')

log.debug('mule started')
```

However, nothing is written to the logfile. For testing purposes I start UWSGI with local user's uid, permissions on the log file are correct (also tried chmod 777 to the same end).
When starting the script as a standalone (as the same user as abose) logging works as expected.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you show the script? Does it work aside from logging?